# jQuery Load() Causes Infinite Loop When IMG.SRC Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

I have a function like this:

```
$('img#foo').load(function(){
    // do something
    $(this).attr('src',newsrcurl) ;
}) ;
```

SRC changing cause re-call load function, so infinite loop!

How to stop load binding?

Comment: return false; after $(this).attr('src',newsrcurl) ;

Comment: Thank you, I have tried it already :)

Comment: did you try e.preventDefault();

Comment: No, but "$(this).unbind('load');" worked, thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attaching the 'load' handler with `.one()` will ensure it only fires once.

```
$('img#foo').one('load', function(){
    // do something
    $(this).attr('src',newsrcurl) ;
}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the URL actually changed before setting it:

```
if ($(this).attr('src') !== newsrcurl) {
   $(this).attr('src', newsrcurl) ;
}
```

Comment: This is a solution also, but not sure